# Collections.sort seems to generate incorrect results

Tags: java, collections

The following code work except for specific inputs.

For instance the following input, -1795085364 stay as the last value, despite being the smallest. I am using java 13.

`{306474574, 642543743, -752837577, 1030910205, 353252387, -1028696876, 2145575295, 2142057380, 66066294, -1795085364};`

```
    private static void sortAndFilter(int[] nums) {
         List<int[]> numsIndexed = new ArrayList<int[]>(nums.length);
        for( int i = 0 ; i< nums.length; i++){
            int[] valAndIndex ={ nums[i],i };
            numsIndexed.add( valAndIndex );
        }
        Collections.sort(numsIndexed, (a,b) -> a[0] - b[0]);

        //rest of code here 
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(a, b) -> a[0] - b[0]` is not a valid comparator.  Nor is `(a, b) -> a - b`.

Both fail to handle numerical overflow correctly. Use Integer.compare -- or, better, use `Comparator.comparingInt(a -> a[0])`.

Answer (score 1):

int value range from -2147483648 to 2147483647 but your sort operation return an outbound values.
If your values still inside the range you can try this

```
Collections.sort(numsIndexed, (a,b) -> (a[0] < b[0]) ? -1 : ((a[0] == b[0]) ? 0 : 1));
```

In sort `Collections.sort(numsIndexed, (a,b) -> Integer.compare(a[0], b[0]))`
Or using `long[]` instead of `int[]`

Comment: Comparators must return 0 for equivalent elements.

Comment: yeah, I just forgot it. I updated my answer. Thanks

Comment: There is no need for all those brackets, `Collections.sort(numsIndexed, (a, b) -> a[0] < b[0]? -1: a[0] == b[0]? 0: 1);` will do.

Answer (score 1):

Try running the following:

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] a = new int[] {306474574, 642543743, -752837577, 1030910205, 353252387, -1028696876, 2145575295, 2142057380, 66066294, -1795085364};
        for (int k=1; k<a.length; ++k)
        {
            for (int j=0; j<k; ++j)
            {
                System.out.format("%d + %d = ", a[j], a[k]);
                System.out.println(a[j]+a[k]);
                System.out.format("%d - %d = ", a[j], a[k]);
                System.out.println(a[j]-a[k]);
            }
        }
    }
```

You should notice some strange results. For example, take a look at `2142057380 - -1795085364`. Your lambda function uses subtraction and will, at some point in time, do this calculation.

Therefore, it seems like your simple subtraction will not cut it. If you are keen on writing your own comparator, you can always add code to handle overflow and underflow.

The following lambda function will actually do exactly what you want without any subtraction and hence without possibility of overflow:

```
(a,b) -> ( (a[0] == b[0]) ? 0 : ( (a[0] > b[0]) ? 1 : -1 ) )
```

This is as fast as it gets if you stay within the realm of compiling to Java bytecode.

Comment: Why these inconsistent two print statements? Why not a single `System.out.printf("%d - %d = %d%n", a[j], a[k], a[j]-a[k]);`?